# Webpack vs NPM Scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, npm-scripts

There are certain tasks or procedures that both npm scripts and webpack can perform.  For example:

- Image & SVG optimization
- CSS and JS minification
- Process sass, postcss, etc.
- And more...

What I would like to know is about the differences and advantages of each solution.  For example:

**Differences**

1. Are there things that Webpack can do that npm scripts cannot do
2. Are there things that npm scripts can do that webpack cannot do

**Advantages**

1. What are the advantages of webpack over npm scripts
2. What are the advantages of npm scripts over webpack

An example of an 'advantage' would be performance; namely, that x is faster then y at a certain task or procedure.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: I do not think that `Wepback` is comparable with `npm scripts`. `Webpack` is a bundler. The major task of Webpack is to transform source files graph (including different kinds of assets) into set of deliverables/chunks.
`npm scripts` is like shell. You can do anything with `npm scripts` event execute webpack) There are lots of CLI packages. But `npm scripts` have no abstraction of the source files grapth.